# Python 3.6 with Pywinrm remotely

Tags: python

How to execute powershell remotely from linux using python 3.6 with Winrm.

I tried but the code is not executing run_ps command. kindly help

Comment: Probably using [pywinrm](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm).  Can you provide your code?

Comment: HI alex, thannks for the reply. I got the answer. Ya using Pywinrm we can do. In Python 3.6 we need to handle std_err output thats all. In python 2.7 it works without any handling.